# How to get Available Product Listing Sort By category data on front end?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show Product listing sort data on left side on catalog page on front-end.

[image]

**Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('CATEGORY ID')->getAvailableSortBy()** returns empty array and if i manually select each sort option from category then it prints array with options .

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
```

will get you all available attributes.

Keep in mind that this will override any "per category"/"per scope" sort by.

Comment: thanks @Yiorgos this works . This also worked for me : `Mage::getModel('catalog/category_attribute_source_sortby')->getAllOptions()`